# How can I print out records from a file where the number of letters in a field exceeds a threshhold using awk?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

This is what I have right now (I know it's not right) `awk '$2 >= 4' cars`

I want to display the records from a file named 'cars' where column 2 has four or more letters in it.

Comment: `length($2) > 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c.f. [GNU `awk`'s manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) - use `length()`.

```
 awk 'length($2) >3' cars
```

This doesn't actually "print out the number of letters in a line in a file" though. Is this what you wanted, or can you clarify your needs?

Comment: This is what I wanted, Thank you!